# Upgrade RAM MacBook Pro MD101

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I have a MacBook Pro MD101 with 2 x 2GB RAM. I want to upgrade to 2 x 4GB but, I don't know where to buy it from? All online shops I've found only sell Corsair PC10666.

I think I want to upgrade my MacBook Pro to 2 x 8GB with PC12800 (1600 Mhz) so I tried to get Corsaire with PC12800. Can my MacBook Pro support this configuration? I read that officially Apple MD101 only supports a maximum of 4 GB RAM for 1 slot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by *Macbook Pro MD101* you mean a Mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro (MacBookPro9,2) model?

If so, while Apple only officially supports a maximum of 8GB RAM, real world tests have proven this model is capable of using 16GB of RAM (and many many people run it with 16GB with no issues). To do this you would install an 8GB chip in each slot.

Now, as you seem to know, this model has two memory slots and takes 204-pin PC3-12800 (1600 MHz) DDR3 SO-DIMM memory chips.

Depending on your location, you can purchase RAM for this model from:

- [MacSales](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3_1600MHz_SDRAM) (United States)
- [Flexx](http://www.flexxmemory.co.uk/categories/apple-mac-memory.html) (United Kingdom)
- [RAM City](https://www.ramcity.com.au/upgrade/apple/macbook-pro/macbookpro9-2-mid-2012-non-retina-13-inch-i5-i7/2325) (Australia)
- [Simply Mac](https://simplymac.sg/collections/memory/products/owc-ddr3l-1600-memory) (Asia)

**If your MacBook Pro is not the Mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro (MacBookPro9,2) model, please ensure you use the various websites above to identify the memory you need!**

Comment: [Data Memory Systems](http://www.datamemorysystems.com/) has been supplying our school in the US with untold terabytes of RAM over the past decade or so. Very reliable with an excellent return policy. Disclaimer: completely satisfied customer - no financial ties to the company.